# Tensor product by a Invertible sheaf is exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, tensor-products

Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{L}\in Qcoh(X)$ an invertible sheaf. Define the following functor:
$Qcoh(X)\to Qcoh(X),\mathcal{M}\mapsto \mathcal{M\otimes L}$
Is it an exact functor? I think it should be for it is locally exact, but I ask to be sure.

Comment: Yes, it is exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove this from the unanswered list: yes, this functor is exact - it is even an equivalence of categories with inverse given by $-\otimes \mathcal{L}^{-1}$.